# Default css for custom html tags?

Tags: html, css, browser

I sometimes use custom html tags as containers for other elements:

```
<message-panel></message-panel>
```

Does an unknown element like the above have a default set of styles, common among the major browsers?

And, is it possible to set a default style for all unknown elements on a page?

Comment: you cannot target all unknown tags only via CSS. Why can't you simply style the set of tags you use one-by-one? can't be that many.

Comment: You could style all unknown elements using javascript, but...it's ugly

Comment: This post is a non sense, all answers to the question got downvote.

Comment: I could certainly style each tag separately. I'm just curious if it is necessary, and perhaps also how much styling I need to add as a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All unknown elements have a computed display value of “inline” [source](https://www.impressivewebs.com/default-css-display-values-html-elements/)

You can use

```
* { ... }
```

for all elements, however this means that you overwrite anything non-specific set for default elements too.

It's better to keep to using HTML5 defined tags unless you're doing something along the lines of webcomponents.